# ZMQ и QML not function

Tags: qt5, qml, zmq

Всем привет, пытаюсь создать приложение на `qml`  с использованием `zmq`.

Версия `QtCreator 5.5`

Есть сервер `zmq publisher`. 
Пытаюсь сделать приложения `qml`, в котором буду отправлять запросы на сервер и получать какие-то данные, **проблема заключается в том, что не получается связать `zmq` и `qml`**.

В режиме отладки, во время нажатия на кнопку, функция не передает параметр в `cpp`.

Для проверки связи я пытаюсь по клику на одну из кнопок передать на сервер `true` или `false`, но в выводе появляются следующие уведомления:

Вывод приложения:

1. `QObject::connect: No such signal ApplicationWindow_QMLTYPE_11::qmlSignal(QString)in (main.cpp: QObject::conntect(root,SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)), handlerSignals, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));`
2. `qrc:/main.qml: TypeError: Property 'onButton_clicked' of object HandlerSignals(0x7fffa9a6d750) is not a function)`

Начал изучение недавно, строго не судите. Спасибо за внимание

Версия qt5.5

```
Client.h(handlersignals)

class HandlerSignals : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit HandlerSignals(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~HandlerSignals();

public slots:
    void cppSlot(const QString &msg);

private slots:
    void onButton_clicked(const bool on);

    void offButton_clicked(const bool off);

    void OnStateReceived(bool isEnabled, unsigned long counter);

signals:
    void StateReceived(bool isEnabled, unsigned long counter);

private:
    zmq::context_t context;
    zmq::socket_t ctrlSocket;
    zmq::socket_t stateSocket;

    void SendRequest(bool enabled);
    void StateReceiver();
};
```

client.cpp(handlersignals)

```
HandlerSignals::HandlerSignals(QObject *parent):
    QObject(parent),
    context(3), ctrlSocket(context, ZMQ_REQ), stateSocket(context, ZMQ_SUB)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(StateReceived(bool,ulong)), this, SLOT(OnStateReceived(bool,ulong)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    ctrlSocket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

    QtConcurrent::run(this, &HandlerSignals::StateReceiver);
}
    HandlerSignals::~HandlerSignals()
    {

    }
    void HandlerSignals::cppSlot(const QString &msg)
    {
        qDebug()<<msg;
    }

    void HandlerSignals::SendRequest(bool enabled)
    {
        ZMQ_Proto::Control messageData;
        messageData.set_enabled(enabled);
        zmq::message_t request(messageData.ByteSize());
        messageData.SerializeToArray(request.data(), messageData.ByteSize());

        ctrlSocket.send(request);

        zmq::message_t reply;
        ctrlSocket.recv(&reply);
    }

    void HandlerSignals::StateReceiver()
    {
        stateSocket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
        stateSocket.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, NULL, 0);

        while(1)
        {
            zmq::message_t stateMessage;
            stateSocket.recv(&stateMessage);

            ZMQ_Proto::State stateData;
            stateData.ParseFromArray(stateMessage.data(), stateMessage.size());

            emit StateReceived(stateData.enabled(), stateData.counter());
        }
    }
    void HandlerSignals::onButton_clicked(const bool on)
    {
//        SendRequest(on);
        qDebug()<<on;

    }

    void HandlerSignals::offButton_clicked(const bool off)
    {
        SendRequest(off);
    }

    void HandlerSignals::OnStateReceived(bool isEnabled, unsigned long counter)
    {
       isEnabled = true;
       counter = 5;
    }
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QObject* root = engine.rootObjects()[0];

    HandlerSignals *handlerSignals = new HandlerSignals(root);
    HandlerSignals cpp(root);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("_cpp", &cpp);

    QObject::connect(root, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)), handlerSignals, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));

    return app.exec();
}

main.qml

    import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2


ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button{
        id: button1
        x: 1
        y: 1
        height: 100
        width: 100
        text: "On"

        onClicked: _cpp.onButton_clicked(true)
    }
    Button{
        x: 110
        y: 1
        id: button2
        height: 100
        width: 100
        text: "Off"

        onClicked: _cpp.offButton_clicked(false)
    }

    SpinBox {
        id: counterSpinBox
        x: 149
        y: 129
        selectByMouse: true
        activeFocusOnPress: true
    }

    CheckBox {
        id: stateCheckBox
        x: 16
        y: 129
        text: qsTr("Состояние")

    }
}
```

Всем спасибо

Comment: В плане взаимодействия QML и C++ почитайте например вот это
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, проблема была в том, что в .h файле функции были private